# Two Serializers.py import each other

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 apps in my django project and I have to import their serializers on each other.

app1.serializer.py

`import food.app1 import serializers`

app2.serializer.py

`import food.app2 import serializers`

I am getting the error related to the circular import issue. I there any way I can import the serializer?

Comment: Wouldn't changing imports to `from food.app2 import serializers` and `from food.app1 import serializers` solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you want to import like this

serializer A(serializer B):

serializer B(serializer A):

if this is the case then when you call any of the one serializer it will call another and another will again call other serializer that will go for infinite time. so, there will be circular dependency issue between two serializers.

in this case you have to rethink your logic for using serializers inheritance.

Comment: For now, I tried to import the first serializer on the second serializer like this, `from food import app1` and I just access the serializer with `app1.serializers.<nameOfSerializer>`

Comment: if you want to import in same project from another app you can do it like this:
`from app1.serializers import {serializer_name}`